# C# Include, ThenInclude Select specific fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
  public class Teacher
    {
        Guid ID;
        string Name;
        string Address;
        string Tel;
        ICollection<Student> Students;
    }

    public class Student
    {
        Guid id;
        string Name;
        string Address;
        string Tel;
        ICollection<Teacher> Teachers;
    }
```

As this is a Many-to-Many relationship, EF would create a Junction Table TeacherStudent.  I want to find all teachers and the list of the teacher's students (name only), eg:

```
Teacher1 name:
  Student1 name,
  Student3 name,
  Student5 name,
  Student9 name

Teacher2 name:
  Student1 name,
  Student2 name,
  Student3 name,
  Student9 name
```

I've tried:

`_context.Teacher.Include(x=>x.TeacherStudent).ThenInclude(y=>y.Student);`

This works and Student info is a list under each Teacher.  However, I don't want all the info, I only want the name. I've tried SelectMany but it flattened out the data and I get the Teacher's name repeated for each Student. How can get a list of Student names under the Teacher's name and **not retrieve the fields I don't need** ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you query a `DbSet` then you get a list of entities from that set. If you only want certain properties of those entities then you have to call `Select` and specify the properties you want, projecting them to either a named type with appropriate properties or an anonymous type. The properties you don't want will not simply disappear because you want them to. Your `Teacher` type has a collection of `Student` objects. If you want a collection of `String` objects then you need to use a type that has that property.

Comment: @John I'm very new to EF.  I heard of projecting and mapping.  I'll read up on that.  If I were to use projection, does it mean that EF still would retrieve all the fields before projecting ?  My example here is a simplified version of the table.  So there would be a number of other fields I bring into memory.  Is there a way to select only the fields I want ?  Thanks.

Comment: Every record must have the same format, so every record will have teacher name and student name.  It is entirely up to you to decide how you PRESENT that data, by watching for the teacher name to change so you can do the grouping.  That's not the database's job.

Comment: `_context.Teacher.Select(t => new { t.Name, Students = t.Students.Select(s => s.Name).ToList() });` should produce sql with the minimum columns required to return those results.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I've tried and it seems to work.  I will test further.  Thanks very much.  If you put your comment in the answer, I will accept it.  Thanks again. PS: Oh, looks like there is a similar answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Include` is used to eager load related entities. `Select` is used to project an entity query into a desired data structure, or otherwise retrieve pieces of information about an entity.

So you can get a list of teachers and students' names:

```
var teachers = _context.Teacher
    .Select(t => new 
    {
        t.Id,
        t.Name,
        Students = t.Students.Select(s => new 
        {
            s.Id,
            s.Name
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

What this would return is an anonymous type containing a list of teachers, pulling back just their ID and name, and a collection of Student anonymous types with the student ID and Name.

Typically when reading data with projections it is a good idea to read IDs since you will often want to use this information to either bring up details, remove, or otherwise alter entries.

> If I were to use projection, does it mean that EF still would
> retrieve all the fields before projecting

Projection builds an SQL query to pull back just the fields needed to populate the data structure you request. It doesn't load entities so this is somewhat mutually exclusive to `Include`. You do not need to "include" related entities to use projection.

Eager Loading with `Include` is typically something you will use when performing an update. for instance if you are going to be adding or removing student associations to a Teacher, you will want to load the Teacher and associated Students to ensure that the change tracking understands what you are doing when you go to add or remove students from a Teacher.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I used Projection without Include and it worked.  Thanks again.